# add milliseconds in c

Tags: c, time

I am writing a code in c and I need to add milliseconds to the current time 
So far, i have :

current_time = time(NULL);
loc_time=localtime(&current_time);

however this only gives HH:MM:SS when I need HH:MM:SS:MM

Say the local time is 20:00:00:10. I want to adding 10 milliseconds and display it so it displays 20:00:00:20. I am fairly new to c so any help is much appreciated. I am confused as time is of type int format and, to add milli seconds I will have to add .001 seconds to the current second which is not an int.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139144/definitive-function-for-get-elapsed-time-in-miliseconds

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "localtime()" API only has granularity of seconds (not milliseconds).

Try [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday)

See also:

- [Getting the current time in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756323/getting-the-current-time-in-milliseconds)

If you're on Windows, you can also try QueryPerformanceCounter():

- [How can I get the Windows system time with millisecond resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729169/how-can-i-get-the-windows-system-time-with-millisecond-resolution)